# Trying to persist enabled/disabled state of checkbox on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code here that is used to enable/disable a submit button when clicking a checkbox. This works fine, but I need the disabled/enabled state to persist on a page refresh

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var the_terms = $("#tandcCheck");
        the_terms.click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked"))
                $(".submit").removeAttr("disabled");
            } else {
                $(".submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");  
            }
        });
    });
```

Would a cookie be the best option for this, or a session?

Comment: Did you carry out some SO research yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Any modifications to the HTML won't persist between page calls. Yes, cookies would work, but I would suggest **[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** which is much simpler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Restore the disabled value (if stored earlier)
    if(localStorage.getItem("disabled") === "disabled"){
      $(".submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }

    var the_terms = $("#tandcCheck");
    the_terms.click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked"))
            $(".submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $(".submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");  
        }
        // Record the disabled status in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem("disabled", $(".submit").attr("disabled"));
    });
});
```